# Get AVG() of select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, average

How can I get Average of a result of `select` query

example:

```
select x from dbo.table1 as a
where MONTH(a.mymonth) = 1 AND YEAR(a.myyear) = 2013
```

is it possible to use `AVG()` function?

Comment: what column taht you would like to calculate `AVG`?

Comment: That's the problem, I want to get the average of the result of this query above

Comment: give mu sample records with desired result.

Comment: Never heard of such thing. What output you expect?

Comment: the result of the query above should give me a column,, I want the average of that column resulted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this all you're looking for?

```
select AVG(x)
from dbo.table1
where MONTH(mymonth) = 1 AND YEAR(myyear) = 2013
```

[Sample Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b55ed/2)

Depending on your data type of x, you may want to cast it to a decimal:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(x as decimal))
```

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to use AVG() function?

Yes it is, wrap it around x, so:

```
    select AVG(x) from dbo.table1 as a
    where MONTH(a.mymonth) = 1 AND YEAR(a.myyear) = 2013
```

Here for more info.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to average `x` your `select` query should look like this:

```
Select AVG(x)
from dbo.table1 as a
where MONTH(a.mymonth) = 1 AND YEAR(a.myyear) = 2013
```